# NetworkInfo.isAvailable() returns false

Tags: java, android, networking

I am now working on an all-in-one computer which looks like a PC but runs Android. It is still a prototype and my job is to adapt our App to this computer. One thing is that this computer connects to the network via Ethernet instead of WIFI or mobile networks.
But when I test the network status using the following code:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);   
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
Boolean isAvailable = networkInfo.isAvailable();
```

networkInfo.isAvailable() returns false while networkInfo.isConnected() returns true. And our App is a online video one which works perfectly  before but now can't load data. By the way, this computer can't connect to my computer, so I can't see log from my IDE. Can you come up with any possible conclusions?

Comment: active network may not be the ethernet connetction. check if `networkInfo.getType()` is `TYPE_ETHERNET`. If not device may not be properly configured to use ethernet.

Comment: Yes, I have checked it in a demo, networkInfo.getType() returns ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET.